# SQL: Percentage Missing and Unique Counts of Table Columns

Tags: sql, pivot, unique, missing-data, calculation

Let's say I've got a table with 4 columns.
Of each column I'd like to know:

- the percentage of missing values (null count) and
- unique counts

If I have a table with columns A B C and D,
the desired outcome of the situation above would be for example:

```
Column_Name | PctMissing | UniqueCount
A           | 0.15       | 16
B           | 0          | 320
C           | 0.3        | 190
D           | 0.05       | 8
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of columns, I'd probably just use `union all`:

```
select 'a' as Column_Name,
  1.0*count(case when a is null then 1 end)/count(*) as PctMissing,
  count(distinct a) as UniqueCount
from t
union all
select 'b' as Column_Name,
  1.0*count(case when b is null then 1 end)/count(*) as PctMissing,
  count(distinct b) as UniqueCount
from t
union all
select 'c' as Column_Name,
  1.0*count(case when c is null then 1 end)/count(*) as PctMissing,
  count(distinct c) as UniqueCount
from t
union all
select 'd' as Column_Name,
  1.0*count(case when d is null then 1 end)/count(*) as PctMissing,
  count(distinct d) as UniqueCount
from t
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8761a97/2)

Depending on your database, there are other approaches, but can be more confusing than `union all`.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select 'a' as column_name,
       avg(case when a is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as missing_ratio,
       count(distinct a) as unique_count
from t
union all
select 'b' as column_name,
       avg(case when b is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as missing_ratio,
       count(distinct b) as unique_count
from t
union all
select 'c' as column_name,
       avg(case when c is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as missing_ratio,
       count(distinct c) as unique_count
from t
union all
select 'd' as column_name,
       avg(case when d is null then 1.0 else 0 end) as missing_ratio,
       count(distinct d) as unique_count
from t;
```